# system clock is off by one hour after every reboot

Tags: time, timezone, clock

Every time I start my laptop, the clock is off by exactly one hour. I have to run `ntpdate` to fix it. Next time I restart the laptop, it will be off again.

I have timezone set up correctly.

I am using Debian Wheezy

Any idea what might be the cause ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The system clock and the hardware clock are not the same.  The command `hwclock -r` should show you the time the hardware clock is set to.  If it is incorrect, use the command `hwclock -w` to update it when the time is correct.  If you dual boot with Windows, you will want to use local time. Otherwise, you may want to set the hardware clock to UTC with the command `hwclock -w -u`.  Recheck the hardware clock after setting it.

Check that `/etc/adjtime` is configured correctly. The third line must contain `UTC` (exactly these three characters) if the hardware clock uses UTC, and something else (e.g. empty) if the hardware clock uses local time (in the time zone defined by `/etc/timezone`).

Comment: `man rcS` says "The EDITMOTD, RAMRUN and UTC variables are no longer used."

Comment: it says LOCAL on my pc

Comment: @moFEAR If the time is off by an hour after reboots and /etc/adjtime is set to LOCAL, then the machine clock has not been updated after a timezone change.